# Do I need a deep copy?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of objects, say `List<Bar> barlist`. These `Bar` orbjects are rather complicated and I would be happy to get on without deep copying them.

However, I would like to allow the user to modify them using a `BindingSource`, `BindingNavigator` and a `DataGridView`. However, if I set the `DataSource` to my barlist and modify values, the `BindingSource` modifies my list (as it does apparently not hold its own list, or only using shallow copies).

The problem with that is: what if the user wants to discard his changes? I would have to revert them manually or don't apply them to the original list if I give the `BindingSource` a deep-copied list. However, I would like to avoid deep-copying.

Is there an alternative path? Or do I not have a choice but to mark the objects as `Serializable` and deep-copy them?

Comment: I am not clear enough on your problem to post a real answer, but you have you considered one-way binding. If that does not work, I would look into currency managers. I do not think that will help either. You are most likely stuck doing a deep copy.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens one-way binding sounds interesting. I assume it would prevent the bindingSource to modify my data. However I dont think WinForms allows this (as you CAN modify the data, however I dont want to apply these changes directly). It seems like everything leads up to using a deep copy.

Comment: @Kiquenet I just used a deep copy. I will post the code as an answer. (I dont take credit for the code, it is essentially the code that was posted on SO a while ago. Also, it only works for serializable objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I used the following deep clone function to solve the problem. It might not be the nicest solution, but it was sufficient and works just fine (eventhough only for Serializable objects)

```
// Creates a deep copy of an Object
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

You basically need to create a separate object that can restore the state of each Bar to what it was before the user started editing. This is normally easier and less expensive than a deep copy.

Comment: Mementos still need to clone the data held as the initial state, if it's an object rather than an immutable type.

Comment: True, but some of the object data might not be relevant or could be restored using other methods (e.g. methods on the Bar object). In those cases Memento is still better than a deep copy.

Comment: This might work, but still, I will have to save the entire list at least once. The data cannot be loaded/reconstructed without major effort otherwise. I think I will use deep copies then.